# Invoke-SQLcmd not working inside Invoke-command

Tags: sql, powershell, remote-access, sqlcmd

I am currently running a `Invoke-SQLcmd` inside a `Invoke-Command` script block and keep receiving a connection error, The `Invoke-SQLcmd` script works when run on its own but not once wrapped in the `Invoke-Command`.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName "MyserverFQDN" -Credential $Serviceaccount -ScriptBlock {
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "SQLDBFQDN" -Database BizTalkMgmtDb -Query "
USE BizTalkMgmtDb
GO
SELECT        bts_sendport.nvcName, bts_sendport_transport.nvcAddress, nPortStatus, bts_sendport_transport.dtFromTime, 
              bts_sendport_transport.bIsServiceWindow, bts_sendport_transport.dtToTime,
              adm_Adapter.Name As TransportTypeID, bts_application.nvcName AS Application
FROM            bts_sendport With(NOLOCK) INNER JOIN
                         bts_sendport_transport ON bts_sendport.nID = bts_sendport_transport.nSendPortID 
                         INNER JOIN
                         bts_application ON bts_sendport.nApplicationID = bts_application.nID
                         INNER JOIN 
                         adm_Adapter ON bts_sendport_transport.nTransportTypeId = adm_Adapter.Id

WHERE 
nTransportTypeId IS NOT NULL

"
}
```

I then receive the following error:

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL 
Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], SqlException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlExectionError,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand
    + PSComputerName        : "MyServerFQDN"     
ParserError: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], ParserException
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], ParserException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExecutionFailureException,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand
    + PSComputerName        : "MyserverFQDN"
```

Like I said I can run the SQLcmd from my server as the service account and it works fine but if I invoke this from my PC to call my server to use my service account to run the SQLcmd I get that error. Any Idea what happening or how to solve this?

Comment: What are you trying to do? You don't need to use any service account to connect to the database. The *service* account has no special database priviledges. [Invoke-SqlCmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps) has a Credentials parameter as well. Finally the error complains about the *database server name*. It has nothing to do with `Invoke-Command`. It says it can't connect to whatever the actual content of `SQLDBFQDN` points to

Comment: First, have you tried using `Invoke-SqlCmd` with the credentials you want? That's the normal and *secure* way of querying. What you tried to do requires extra priviledges for the remote command. Second, can you execute that `Invoke-SqlCmd` on the server or do you get, as I suspect, the same error? You can use `Enter-PSSession` to open a remote shell and try that command

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos long story short this script has to be run by non admin users to get information from our DBs so it needs to make the SQLcmd call as the service account, from the server as the account isn't allowed to run on their machines. The invoke-sqlcmd doesn't contain credential as an option. As I said in my question the invoke-sqlcmd works with my service account from my server when run. It stops working when run inside the invoke-command section.

Comment: All database users are non-admin users, except the DBAs. All applications connect as *non-admin* users.  And yes, `Invoke-SqlCmd` does have a `Credential` option, that's why I posted the link to the docs. You don't need it though, as the server recognizes the current user's account. Just add the Windows account to the database with limited priviledges. You can add Windows groups too, to avoid adding individual accounts. By default they have no permission to read anything, just give them permission to whatever they need to call

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos If I enter a PSSession and run the invoke-sqlcmd it returns the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that `$SQLDBFQDN` variable inside your script block is defined in a temporary session, different than yours (because it runs in another PowerShell process on the remote computer).

[To use local variable in a remote session](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables?view=powershell-5.1#using-local-variables), try to change it's scope by replacing `$SQLDBFQDN` with `$Using:SQLDBFQDN`:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $MyserverFQDN -Credential $Serviceaccount -ScriptBlock {
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $Using:SQLDBFQDN -Database BizTalkMgmtDb -Query "
USE BizTalkMgmtDb
GO
SELECT        bts_sendport.nvcName, bts_sendport_transport.nvcAddress, nPortStatus, bts_sendport_transport.dtFromTime, 
              bts_sendport_transport.bIsServiceWindow, bts_sendport_transport.dtToTime,
              adm_Adapter.Name As TransportTypeID, bts_application.nvcName AS Application
FROM            bts_sendport With(NOLOCK) INNER JOIN
                         bts_sendport_transport ON bts_sendport.nID = bts_sendport_transport.nSendPortID 
                         INNER JOIN
                         bts_application ON bts_sendport.nApplicationID = bts_application.nID
                         INNER JOIN 
                         adm_Adapter ON bts_sendport_transport.nTransportTypeId = adm_Adapter.Id

WHERE 
nTransportTypeId IS NOT NULL

"
}
```

Comment: Ahh my mistake sorry the variables were just there to replace the actual names I will change them from variables sorry and thanks.